# Vimeo embed auto mute on load

Tags: javascript, html, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I have a vimeo embedded video but cant seem to integrate the mute on load.

Here is my video code

```
<div id="vimeo"> </div> 

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://f.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>
```

and the js using

```
 <script>
// URL of the video 
        var videoUrl = 'http://www.vimeo.com/76979871?api=1?player_Id=vimeoyo';

        var endpoint = 'http://www.vimeo.com/api/oembed.json';
        var callback = 'embedVideo';
        var url = endpoint + '?url=' + encodeURIComponent(videoUrl)+ '&autoplay=true' + '&callback=' + callback + '&width=420';
        function embedVideo(video) {
            document.getElementById('vimeo').innerHTML = unescape(video.html);
        }
        function init() {
            var js = document.createElement('script');
            js.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
            js.setAttribute('src', url);
            document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(js);
            var player = 'vimeoyo';
            player.api('setVolume', 0);
        }


        window.onload = init;


  </script>
```

The issue im having also is that the video isn't an iframe.

Edit: There is an answer to mute using an iframe.  here

[Muting an embedded vimeo video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649641/muting-an-embedded-vimeo-video)

But having tested that using this fiddle, it also doesnt seem to mute the video.  http://jsfiddle.net/serversides/gfcpjLsy/

Comment: Did you try playing different values for `player.api('setVolume', 0);` on the `js` file?

Comment: I have tried but I can't get any of the api to work even though I have put in ?api=1 into the video URL.

Comment: When it comes to `froogaloop` there are two important things: give your `iframe` an `id`, and add that to the Vimeo src url as `player_id=%%ID%%` and also include `api=1` in that URL string. Also, where is your iframe? It is not added with JS nor in your HTML...

Comment: JSFiddle wont load the code for the oEmbed example.  However there is this at the most basic level http://jsfiddle.net/serversides/gfcpjLsy/ this was taken from another SO question and yet it doesnt mute either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're dinamically creating the `iframe` from the vimeo api, you should only set the volume after the iframe is loaded. So, in your `embedVideo` function, after you insert the HTML into your `div`, you must get the first child of the `div` (it's the `iframe`), and you add an `onload` event to it.

After the iframe is loaded, then you must use the froogaloop's `$f` function to encapsulate the iframe into its library, and then you can use the `api` method to set the volume to zero.

In your example, you were trying to call the `api` method in a `string`, and it would never work.

```
function embedVideo(video) {
  var div = document.getElementById('vimeo');
  div.innerHTML = unescape(video.html);

  var ifr = div.firstChild;
  ifr.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
    var player = $f(ifr);
    player.api('setVolume', 0);
  });
}

function init() {
  var js = document.createElement('script');
  js.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
  js.setAttribute('src', url);
  document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(js);
}
```

I've created a [plnkr for you](http://plnkr.co/edit/U4CsnAuueic4sbvLUnZV?p=preview), with your example working.

Comment: Thankyou thats awesome!  Was racking my brain for ages trying to work out why it wasn't muting!

Answer (score 1):

**Here is my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/jakeoblivion/phytdt9L/5/

(You will need your own play/pause mute/unmute icons)

```
  //load video muted
  var video = $("#myvideo");
  video.vimeo("play");
  video.vimeo("setVolume", 0);

    //toggle play/pause
  $('#play-pause').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('play');
    if ($(this).hasClass('play')) {
      //pause video
      video.vimeo("pause");
      $(this).css('background', 'url("http://unclebarts.co.uk/wp-content/themes/bungabunga_bootstrap/img/video-controls/play.png") no-repeat');
    } else {
      //unpause video
      video.vimeo("play");
      $(this).css('background', 'url("http://unclebarts.co.uk/wp-content/themes/bungabunga_bootstrap/img/video-controls/pause.png") no-repeat');
    }
  });

  //toggle mute/unmute
  $('#mute-unmute').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('mute');
    if ($(this).hasClass('mute')) {
      //unmute video
  video.vimeo("setVolume", 1);
      $(this).css('background', 'url("http://unclebarts.co.uk/wp-content/themes/bungabunga_bootstrap/img/video-controls/volume.png") no-repeat');

    } else {
      //mute video
  video.vimeo("setVolume", 0);
      $(this).css('background', 'url("http://unclebarts.co.uk/wp-content/themes/bungabunga_bootstrap/img/video-controls/mute.png") no-repeat');
    }
  });
```

Spent ages trying and nothing seemed to work to.

I just wanted to have a Vimeo autoplay muted (volume 0) with simple Play/Pause Mute/Unmute controls, instead of their default ones.

(if you want to add the default controls back but keep muted, remove "?background=1". By default background=1 will set video.vimeo("setVolume", 0) and hide controls, so I also added the mute on load without the background=1 set).

Also note: "You’ll need to be running on a web server instead of opening the file directly in your browser. Flash and JS security restrictions will prevent the API from working when run locally."

http://www.taxidermyart.co.uk