# Mute + Autoplay several vimeo video

Tags: javascript, video, iframe, vimeo, mute

I would like to embed several video on an artist website, on autoplay and mute.
I have managed to mute one with the help of : [Muting an embedded vimeo video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649641/muting-an-embedded-vimeo-video)
but with several video it doesn't work, the video stops automatically
So then I added `&autopause=0` and both videos play, but the sound is back!

HTML :

```
<iframe id="vimeo_player" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/101835861?api=1&player_id=vimeo_player&autopause=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&title=0&portrait=0" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

<iframe id="vimeo_playerr" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/57277798?api=1&player_id=vimeo_player&autopause=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Script

```
  <script src="https://f.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>

 $(function() {
      var vimeo_iframe = $('#vimeo_player')[0];
      var player = $f(vimeo_iframe);

      player.addEvent('ready', function() {
          player.api('setVolume', 0);
      });

      var vimeo_iframer = $('#vimeo_playerr')[0];
      var playerr = $f(vimeo_iframer);

      playerr.addEvent('ready', function() {
          playerr.api('setVolume', 0);
      });

  });
```

Has any of you any idea of how I could solve this?

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly try adding &background=1 to the src url instead of &autoplay=0