# Vimeo autoplay not working Safari 11

Tags: safari, vimeo, autoplay

I've loaded this embed code to our website on the homepage.

https://player.vimeo.com/video/254985863?autoplay=1&loop=1&autopause=0&background=1" width="1903" height="500" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>

You can see the site [here](http://pointsmith.com)

The video autoplays perfectly everywhere except Safari. In Safari it just loads the cover image. I am guessing that safari 11 thinks the video has sound but it doesn't. Is there a setting to show safari that this is a muted video?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find a solution to this? Thanks

Comment: No, unfortunately for now we just changed our vimeo cover image to be something we are okay with Safari users seeing landing on the page. The autoplay works everywhere except Safari still.

Comment: Do you get a NotAllowedError in the console, like in this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/46444058/247696

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a very recent Safari bug, possibly in 11.0.3 or 11.0.2. I've just reported this to Apple, please do the same so that they get on it: https://www.apple.com/feedback/safari.html

It's definitely treating the video as if it has sound - if you set the 'Settings for this website' to 'allow all autoplay' then it will work - which is useless because the default is 'Stop Media with sound'

Comment: Thank you - I just reported this to apple as well.

Comment: it is not a bug, see official site, link in my answer

Answer (score 0):

We were experiencing the same issue with Safari (only) for background video and I have been paying close attention to this thread since it was raised back in February (I did report the issue to Apple as suggested) but upon checking the live site again today this is now working correctly once again.

Neither the Vimeo videos or website code has been changed but the videos are now playing in Safari as expected (previously it was displaying a static image only).  I am still running the same version of Safari as I was before, when this was an issue (11.0.3), so I can only assume that something has changed on the Vimeo embed side of things.  Perhaps they have updated the mute code.

It is now working correctly again, but I can find no mention of anything changing on the Vimeo side.

Comment: I'm still receiving this as of June 2018.  Works perfectly fine in Chrome/FF, and completely randomly works in Safari 10% of the time.

Comment: It's strange.  It was an issue for me when I originally commented on this ticket but it subsequently started working.  I have just tested again and it is still working as expected for for me in Safari (11.0.3) with background video without sound streaming from Vimeo.  From my perspective this was a temporary blip, it has been working since March.  I struggle to explain what the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

on https://www.apple.com/safari/

"Stop auto-play videos.
Safari prevents unexpected and unwanted videos with audio from automatically playing while you browse. Just click the play button if you want to view them. Have a favorite site where you always want videos to play? Use per‑site settings in Safari to enable media auto-play."

Comment: this explains the problem, but doesn't provide a solution to the OPs question

Comment: Up to you, what is the solution since autoplay can't work on Safari ? @Skandix